# VLCJ: Packaged Jar cant load libvlc library when double-clicked but runs perfectly through console

Tags: java, vlcj

I have a problem with vlc.I am using Eclipse and have made a small application to play video files using vlcj framework.Inside Eclipse everything works fine but when I make jar executable file through Eclipse and double-clicking it (on Windows 64: Tested only on this platform) nothing happens .Then I'm trying using "cd myjarfilepath" and then "java -jar myjarname.jar" and everything works fine.Why this is happening and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance to stackoverflow's community .

Edit:

In Path Location: C:\Users\user\Documents\31\Latest_Win64\Needed I have the following files:

```
plugins(directory)  
axvlc.dll  
axvlc.dll.manifest  
libvlc.dll  
libvlc.dll.manifest  
libvlccore.dll  
npvlc.dll  
npvlc.dll.manifest  
vlc.exe.manifest
```

In my classpath i have included the following files:

```
jna-3.5.1.jar  
platform-3.5.1.jar  
vlcj-2.2.0.jar  
vlcj-2.2.0-javadoc.jar  
vlcj-2.2.0-sources.jar
```

Comment: Does this only happen with this particular jar - does it work for all other jars? If so, VLCJ may be a red herring.

Comment: @berry120 Yes, happens only in vlcj based projects.That's why i ask for a solution.That's my problem with the great vlcj framework.

Comment: Actually, to check with normal applications i am loading the vlcj dlls in my constructor so that my JFrame doesn't even appear if the libraries dont load successfuly.If i load those dlls lets say after pressing a button then the JFrame appears, but of course media cant be played.

Comment: Is it possible to check this out with a simple Swing application?

Comment: ....because it maybe my computer's problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue loading the needed VLCj files.  Not only are dlls required but the plugin directory is also required.  As the execution location moves around from inside eclipse to back in the file system, the path to these files may be getting set incorrectly.

It sounds like you have it working within eclipse.  This would indicate to me that what you have should work.  Firstly, I would recommend acquiring the VLC dlls, etc., by providing this as a VM argument such as shown below, rather that setting it in code.  Remember to comment out any loading you are doing in your code so that you are relying on the command line argument.

```
-Djna.library.path={Application Location}/lib
example: -Djna.library.path=C:/myapp/lib


Directory Contents:
lib
-- libblc.dll
-- libvlc5.dll
-- {etc}
/plugins
   /3dnow
   /access
   {etc}
```

If you are still having issues, add the following argument to put VLCj into debug mode.  This can be very helpful to determine where things are failing.

```
-Dvlcj.log=DEBUG
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Without using any loading code i tried to use -Djna.library.path=C:/Users/user/Documents/31/Latest_Win64/Needed but now it doesnt run from jar and console(Only from eclipse).I have placed required files in a folder in C:\Users\user\Documents\31\Latest_Win64\Needed including the plugins directory.Just in case i will edit my post for more details in that Needed folder.I appreciate your help however.

Comment: A long shot, but, are you using the same Java version in Eclipse that you are using outside of Eclipse?  I had a problem once with vlcj where I was using 32-bit Java in Eclipse and it worked but it would not work with 64-bit Java running in Windows 7.  Vlcj is very picky about 32 vs. 64-bit.

Comment: I found that inside eclipse i use 64 bit java and outside 32 bit using this command/instruction : System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") );

Comment: Inside Eclipse it prints the message in console so in order to see that message from my app outside Eclpise i just draw it graphically and you were right :) it differs.

Comment: How can i use 64 bit jvm to run my application outside eclipse?

Comment: I got the required files for vlc 32 bit and now jar works perfectly when double-clicking because it uses 32 bit jvm.But not with console which runs jar file with 64 bit version of jre